# data manipulation/ indexing python vs R

Tags: python, r

I am inexperienced with python and am unsure what i should search for this particular task. I am trying to find a way to index a list much like i would index a vector in R:

## R

```
vec=c(1,2,3)

> vec==1

[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

## python

```
>>> list_a=[1,2,3]
>>> list_a==1
False
```

## separate attempt in python

```
for i in list_a:
...     i==1
... 
False
False
False
```

Notice above that it is False for all three values even though the first value is 1???

## And yet

```
>>> for i in list_a:
...     if i==1:
...             print('hello')
... 
hello
```

Hence when it comes to python I am just looking for a way to index the the python list in the same way as i can I'm R???

Comment: Lists are only equal to lists containing the same things. You either need to check them element-wise, or switch to numpy, a `numpy.array` will behave as you expect it to. Note that python+data usually spells numpy, so you should get familiar. Native python (using a list comprehension): `[i==1 for i in list_a]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about :

```
>>> [x == 1 for x in list_a]
[True, False, False]
```

Answer (score 3):

an alternative:

```
map(lambda x: x == 1, list_a)
#[True, False, False]
```